# Resize and set a font color to my alert message

Tags: ios, swift, alert

I am looking for a little help. I'd want to resize(reduce) and set a font color(blue for instance) to the alert message function:

```
func WrongMessage(theMessage: String) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hey",  message:"theMessage", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alertController.view.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:theMessage2, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: 2 errors: message:theMessage instead of message:"theMessage"

Comment: title:theMessage instead of title:theMessage2

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31997885/how-to-create-custom-uialertcontroller-in-swift-ios).
Basically you're going to have to make a custom UIAlertView, where you can customize anything in the alert. I don't know of a way to do it with the basic UIAlertController class.