# Display fullscreen alerts in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, alertview

How can I show full screen AlertViews in Swift. What I have done is added a UIView(custom alert view) on top of View controller in storyboard. Is there any other way to do it?

[image]

Comment: Do you not like this approach because it uses storyboards? Because it covers up the other views in the VC? Something else? Also, are you going to show this alert in multiple places? If so, doing this on every view controller in the storyboard might be a pain...

Comment: It will be in multiple controllers but will have different views like some have images other have text and buttons

Answer (score 0):

It is better to create a xib file that contains your `custom alert view` and subclass it to `UIView` for custom properties and methods. And just programatically show it in your `view controller`.

You can check this out on how to implement it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39586736/11138557

Happy coding :D